# Sections of smooth morphisms over henselian rings

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, local-rings

Let $(A,\mathfrak m)$ be a henselian local ring. Let $R$ and $S$ be $A$-algebras of finite type and $f\colon R\to S$ be a smooth morphism. Assume that the induced morphism $R/\mathfrak m R\to S/\mathfrak m S$ has a section. Does it imply that $f$ has a section?

If $A$ is $\mathfrak m$-complete, this seems to be true: one can lift $f$ to $R/\mathfrak m^n R$ inductively using a smoothness criterion. This makes the full statement plausible because $A$ is just the ''algebraic substitute of the completion''. I am willing to assume things about $A$, $R$, and $S$. E.g., that $A$ contains a field.

Comment: Some extra assumptions are needed, otherwise take $A=k[[t]]$, $R=A[1/t]=k((t))$, $S = R[X]/(X^2 - t) = k((t^{1/2}))$. The special fibers are empty.

Comment: The reason is that $(R, \mathfrak{m} R)$ is usually not a henselian pair. For a less silly example that the one above, try $A=k[[t]]$, $R=A[X]$, $S=R[Y]/(Y(tX-1)-1) = R[1/(tX-1)]$. Then $R/tR\to S/tS$ is an isomorphism while $R\to S$ does not have a section. However, the henselizations of $(R, tR)$ and $(S, tS)$ coincide.

Comment: @PiotrAchinger, of course you are right. The statement is wrong even for complete rings for a similar reasion: $(R,\mathfrak m R)$ is rarely $\mathfrak m$-complete.